# WebRTC not working even after using the turn servers from Twilio

Tags: twilio, webrtc, turn

ICE candidates are getting closed after few seconds of waiting. Working fine in local network. But not working when the peers are on different networks even though i am using TURN servers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure you have the proper ports/protocols enabled?

[What are Twilio Client's Network Connectivity Requirements?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180888-What-are-Twilio-Client-s-Network-Connectivity-Requirements-)

The [Twilio Network Testing Tool](https://networktest.twilio.com/) may also be useful.

Comment: Instead of using other other js webrtc libraries, i am using the twillio php and js sdk for video. Now i am able to see the video even if the clients are on different networks within a peer to peer room.

Comment: That should work, as long as the necessary ports and protocols are open on both networks. For Twilio Programmable Video, that will be found here - https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/ip-address-whitelisting.